# Tesseract can't recognise simpliest text

Tags: tesseract

I'm new to Tesseract and investigating how it works.
But in some cases it failes to recognise the simpliest text ("0")

I've checked the processed image and it looks pretty clear to me.

Any suggestions what might be wrong?

Source image: [image: Source image] and tessinput.tif: [image]

```
$ ./tesseract.exe /c/dev/git/fifa/proclubs-stats/assist.png stdout conf.txt

Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 450
Empty page!!
Estimating resolution as 450
Empty page!!
```

Comment: Did you read tesseract documentation? Did you try to sear for a solution on StackOverflow?

Comment: Try with PSM 6 or 10.